# How to insert a struct in a list by alphabetic order

Tags: c, list, struct

Well, i have a code that inserts a new struct in a list in alphabetically order but i'm with a little problem. I just can make it work has a function and when i call i make head = Insert(frota* head, char name). The code is the fallowing

```
typedef struct robot {
   int bateria;
   char nome[3];
   int pos_x;
   int pos_y;
   int target_x;
   int target_y;
   int limpos;
   int percorridos;
   struct robot * next;
}frota;

frota* Insert(frota* head, char name){
frota* temp = (frota*)malloc(sizeof(frota));
if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Unable to allocate memory for new node\n");
        exit(-1);
}
temp->nome[0] = 'R';
temp->nome[1] = name;
int* prevtemp = head;
int* nexttemp = head;
if(head != NULL)
    {
        // Corner Case: First on the list
        if(temp->nome[1] <= prevtemp->nome[1])
        {
            head = temp;
            temp->next = prevtemp;
        }
        else
        {
            // CASE: Somewhere between the first and the list
            while(nexttemp->next != NULL)
            {
                nexttemp = nexttemp->next;
                if(temp->nome[1] >= prevtemp->nome[1] && temp->nome[1] <= nexttemp->nome[1])
                {
                    prevtemp->next = temp;
                    temp->next = nexttemp;
                    break;
                }
                prevtemp = prevtemp->next;
            }

            // Corner Case: end of list
            if(nexttemp->next == NULL)
            {
                nexttemp->next = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // Corner Case: We had an empty list
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

My question is how to make the code to work and changing the value directly of the value head, making this way this function a procedure. The code that i tried is this:

```
void Insert(frota* head, char name){
frota* temp = (frota*)malloc(sizeof(frota));
if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Unable to allocate memory for new node\n");
        exit(-1);
}
temp->nome[0] = 'R';
temp->nome[1] = name;
int* prevtemp = *head;
int* nexttemp = *head;
if(*head != NULL)
    {
        // Corner Case: First on the list
        if(temp->nome[1] <= prevtemp->nome[1])
        {
            *head = temp;
            temp->next = prevtemp;
        }
        else
        {
            // CASE: Somewhere between the first and the list
            while(nexttemp->next != NULL)
            {
                nexttemp = nexttemp->next;
                if(temp->nome[1] >= prevtemp->nome[1] && temp->nome[1] <= nexttemp->nome[1])
                {
                    prevtemp->next = temp;
                    temp->next = nexttemp;
                    break;
                }
                prevtemp = prevtemp->next;
            }

            // Corner Case: end of list
            if(nexttemp->next == NULL)
            {
                nexttemp->next = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // Corner Case: We had an empty list
        *head = temp;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

This way i cal the procedure as Insert(&head,name). Any help would be appreciate. When i run the code it appears segmentation fault and is not na memory error
PS: The code isn't entirely my responsible, found some part online....

Grateful

Comment: Do you get an error?  Or a seg fault?  What do you mean by "this code doesn't run"?

Comment: This looks really bad: `int* prevtemp = head;` (with `head` being a `frota**`).

Comment: Also it looks as if all assignments to `head` should be change to be assignments to `(*head)`, other wise they would not make sense at all, while provoking UB anyways.

Comment: The error that i get is this: "convert 'frota** {aka robot**}' to 'int*' in initialization". @alk it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Why the `int *`, I see no reason to introduce a pointer to `int` in this context in any way.... :-S

Comment: That was what my programming teacher told that was the problem....I just want to save the pointer....i have to use the same struc?

Comment: Use same type for same things. You should not assign an apple to a pie.

Comment: Ah, ok, understood :D

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

Change

```
int* prevtemp;
```

to be

```
struct robot * prevtemp;
```

(same for `nexttemp`)

---

Change all

```
head
```

to

```
(*head)
```

---

Change all

```
frota
```

to

```
struct robot
```

Comment: But changing my head to (*head) i will not be changing the value of the head?

Comment: @luisdias: I suspect it will. To be sure however you might like to show us how you call `Insert()`.

Comment: Insert(&head,name). I think it will...because in my code i'm changing the position of the pointer head....Some of the modifications that you've refered will not make any difference like this: "frota* temp to  struct robot * temp;".

Comment: Just drop this `frota` typedef, it's of no use and just makes to code less readbel.

Comment: As you want the value of `head` on caller level to be changed from inside `Insert()` you pass the address of `head` by using `&`. So the access the actual value of `head` inside `Insert()` you need to use the de-reference operator `*` inside `Insert()`.

Comment: Ok, lets see if i understood....i pass the value of head...but i don't want to change it....just want to modify the values of the next...just use *head inside code and there is no conflict there?